# Can we reconstruct the region in the xy plane by length measurements?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Consider a closed smooth bounded curve enclosing a region $S$ in the XY-plane $\mathbb{R} ^2$.

We define the function $f(x)$, where $x$ is a point on the $x$ axis, as the length of the intersection of the line paralell to the $y$-axis which goes through $x$, with the set $S$, so it can have multiple components and we know the total length.

Suppose we know the same function for some coordiante systems rotated relative to the xy system. Can we reconstruct $S$ using only this data? How many coordinate systems do we need?

Answer (score 3):

A key search term is *geometric tomography*.
The problem posed is a version of Hammer’s X-ray reconstruction problem:

> Gardner, Richard J., and Markus Kiderlen. "A solution to Hammer's X-ray reconstruction problem." *Advances in Mathematics* 214.1 (2007): 323-343.
>   [PDF download](http://home.math.au.dk/kiderlen/preprints/gard:kide07.pdf)

---

[image: Xrays]

          

<sup>Two shapes with the same parallel X-rays.</sup>

---

Comment: But to what extent does this answer the question?

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Unless I misunderstand the question, one cannot reconstruct $S$ from the lengths of parallel ray intersections.

Comment: My understanding is that we are supposed to consider lengths coming from multiple directions, not just the ones from segments parallel to the y-axis.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: You are right; I misinterpreted. Then rotate the blue rays $90^\circ$. They yield the same length intersections. So two directions do not always suffice.

Comment: Yes... but now choose a third direction. I thought the question was asking if there are a finite number of directions we could choose that would determine the curve. (Admittedly, the question could stand some more clarification.)

Comment: @ToddTrimble: This is a version of "Hammer’s X-ray reconstruction problem." I will edit my response.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that's helpful! On the second page it seems to indicate that no set of three directions will suffice, but there are sets of four directions which will work for all curves with convex interior. Would that extend to all simple closed curves, convex or not?

Comment: @ToddTrimble: I think nonconvexity introduces significant complications. Not certain of the status. Might be unsolved.